# Grails 3.2 with Intellij cannot extend plugin class

Tags: gradle, grails

I have a base plugin class that cannot be resolved.  It is like this:

package my.project
class NotificationController extends my.notification.plugin.NotificationController {...}

Upon building, the error I receive is
Error:(11, 1) Groovyc: unable to resolve class my.notification.plugin.NotificationController

Same thing for the Notification service.

Is this an Intellij thing or a Grails/Gradle thing?  And is there a cure?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is - you can't extend the controller because of the special processing grails applies to a controller.  If one must do this, the base plugin should partition the controller "guts" into a regular class.  Then, both the plugin and the main app can extend the regular class.  Of course this is not quite the same as extending the plugin controller, but it seems to be as close as one can get.  And this assumes one has control of the plugin class code...